# JAVA_HOME error when running Flutter code with Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, java-home, avd-manager

I am setting Flutter for the first time and I keep getting this error when trying to run the Flutter code on a Pixel 2 emulator:

*Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\jdk-16.0.1
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)*

I tried deleting and reinstalling Android Studio and Java SDK, but it does not solve anything.

I tried setting the JAVA_HOME variable in environmental variables with the following path:
*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\jdk-16.0.1*
...but nothing, same error.

Thanks for your help

Important Notice:
My android sdk is installed on the D partition, while the Java sdk is on the C drive. Does it matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open powershell and write java --version

If you dont get the version try to add again the Java_home to path

Nevertheless, I think java home should be on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\jdk-16.0.1\bin directory